# How to check HTML control attributes in Datalist?

Tags: asp.net, html, datalist

I did my code to find **HTML** control " **Source**" and I want to check if "**Src**" attribute have value or not , I tried to add " inner text" but
it return ***NULL*** .

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL_Media" runat="server"  onitemdatabound="DL_Media_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <video width="215" height="160" runat="server"  id="vd" controls>
        <source src='<%# Eval("Media_File")%>' type="video/ogg" 
            runat="server" id="source"></source>
        </video>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>


protected void DL_Media_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl video = e.Item.FindControl("vd") as HtmlGenericControl;
        HtmlGenericControl source = e.Item.FindControl("source") as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (source != null)
        {
            string x = "~/";
            string y = "";
            if (source.InnerText == x)
            {
                video.InnerText.Replace(x, y);

                DL_Media.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HtmlGenericControl source= e.Item.FindControl("source") as HtmlGenericControl;
string src = source.Attributes["src"].ToString();
```

Source: [How to: Read HTML Attributes for Controls in Web Forms Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeesb2c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).